# Pubsub.pull request does not working properly - go

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to pull 1 message at a time from pub-sub subscription using go client libraries. But message are not pulling on pull request even messages are present on subscription. Subscriber is waiting for all messages to be processed.

I am trying basic code in go in which I am pulling one message at a time. I have used two instances, and ran the script(to create subscriber) 4 times at background on both. I have set ack_deadline 10 sec.
I am expecting the result like each subscriber should take next message from subscription after one message acknowledged. But message is not pulling on instance until last messages processing is done. 
Why messages are not pulling after one message processing done? In my knowledge there should not be any dependency on the instances or subscriber.
Let mi know any other changes or parameter need to be set. 
Thanks in advance.

Here is the log of one instance:

```
2019/10/21 05:22:07 Got message: Message 0 at 2019-10-21 05:22:07.022772532 
2019/10/21 05:22:11 Got message: Message 1 at 2019-10-21 05:22:11.330566981 
2019/10/21 05:22:14 Got message: Message 2 at 2019-10-21 05:22:14.803031569 
2019/10/21 05:22:18 Got message: Message 3 at 2019-10-21 05:22:18.452912271 
2019/10/21 05:38:39 Acking message: Message 3 at 2019-10-21 05:38:39.471739478 
2019/10/21 05:39:10 Acking message: Message 0 at 2019-10-21 05:39:10.039336794 
2019/10/21 05:41:22 Acking message: Message 1 at 2019-10-21 05:41:22.351124342 
2019/10/21 05:50:31 Acking message: Message 2 at 2019-10-21 05:50:31.829087762 
2019/10/21 05:50:39 Got message: Message 13 at 2019-10-21 05:50:39.005916608
2019/10/21 05:50:39 Got message: Message 11 at 2019-10-21 05:50:39.00623238 
2019/10/21 05:50:39 Got message: Message 15 at 2019-10-21 05:50:39.007216256
2019/10/21 05:50:39 Got message: Message 12 at 2019-10-21 05:50:39.008066257
```

log of 2nd instance:

```
2019/10/21 05:22:29 Got message: Message 4 at 2019-10-21 05:22:29.331569077 
2019/10/21 05:22:33 Got message: Message 5 at 2019-10-21 05:22:33.018801275 
2019/10/21 05:22:36 Got message: Message 6 at 2019-10-21 05:22:36.803434547 
2019/10/21 05:22:40 Got message: Message 7 at 2019-10-21 05:22:40.409314927 
2019/10/21 05:39:38 Acking message: Message 4 at 2019-10-21 05:39:38.349619635 
2019/10/21 05:42:42 Acking message: Message 6 at 2019-10-21 05:42:42.819874065 
2019/10/21 05:47:40 Acking message: Message 5 at 2019-10-21 05:47:40.049128075 
2019/10/21 05:50:38 Acking message: Message 7 at 2019-10-21 05:50:38.42874031 
2019/10/21 05:50:39 Got message: Message 8 at 2019-10-21 05:50:39.005090906 
2019/10/21 05:50:39 Got message: Message 9 at 2019-10-21 05:50:39.005334146 
2019/10/21 05:50:39 Got message: Message 16 at 2019-10-21 05:50:39.006427796 
2019/10/21 05:50:39 Got message: Message 14 at 2019-10-21 05:50:39.007231713
```

```golang
package main
// [START pubsub_publish_with_error_handling_that_scales]
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    pubsub "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub/apiv1"
    pubsubpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/pubsub/v1"
)


func main(){
    f, _:= os.OpenFile("testlogfile", os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    defer f.Close()
    log.SetOutput(f)
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    pullMsgs("sureline-dev-1264", "sub7")
}

func random(min, max int) int {
    return rand.Intn(max - min) + min
}

func pullMsgs(projectID, subscriptionID string) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := pubsub.NewSubscriberClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()
    sub := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/subscriptions/%s", projectID, subscriptionID)
// Be sure to tune the MaxMessages parameter per your project's needs, and accordingly
// adjust the ack behavior below to batch acknowledgements.
    req := pubsubpb.PullRequest{
        Subscription: sub,
        MaxMessages:  1,
    }

    fmt.Println("Listening..")

    for {
        res, err := client.Pull(ctx, &req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    // client.Pull returns an empty list if there are no messages available in the
    // backlog. We should skip processing steps when that happens.
        if len(res.ReceivedMessages) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        var recvdAckIDs []string
        for _, m := range res.ReceivedMessages {
            recvdAckIDs = append(recvdAckIDs, m.AckId)
        }

        var done = make(chan struct{})
        var delay = 0 * time.Second // Tick immediately upon reception
        var ackDeadline = 10 * time.Second

    // Continuously notify the server that processing is still happening on this batch.
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return
                case <-done:
                    return
                case <-time.After(delay):
                    err := client.ModifyAckDeadline(ctx, &pubsubpb.ModifyAckDeadlineRequest{
                        Subscription:       sub,
                        AckIds:             recvdAckIDs,
                        AckDeadlineSeconds: int32(ackDeadline.Seconds()),
                    })
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }
                    delay = ackDeadline - 5*time.Second // 5 seconds grace period.
                }
            }
        }()

        for _, m := range res.ReceivedMessages {
            // Process the message here, possibly in a goroutine.
            log.Printf("Got message: %s at %v", string(m.Message.Data), time.Now())
            fmt.Printf("Got message: %s at %v", string(m.Message.Data), time.Now())
            myrand := random(240, 420)
            log.Printf("Sleeping %d seconds...\n", myrand)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(myrand)*time.Second)
            err := client.Acknowledge(ctx, &pubsubpb.AcknowledgeRequest{
                Subscription: sub,
                AckIds:       []string{m.AckId},
            })
            log.Printf("Acking message: %s at %v", string(m.Message.Data), time.Now())
            fmt.Printf("Acking message: %s at %v", string(m.Message.Data), time.Now())
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }

        close(done)
    }
}
```

I am expecting the output is like take next message from the subscription after first message processing done. It should not be dependable on any other instances.

Comment: I deleted my answer, I didn't well understood you issue, I didn't well see the log time entry.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to pull a single message at a time in this way is an anti-pattern for Cloud Pub/Sub. In your case, your subscribers probably end up communicating with different servers that have messages allocated to be sent to the subscribers that connect to them. Cloud Pub/Sub expects to receive several pull requests simultaneously from clients that use this method to receive messages. Therefore you should either have several pull requests outstanding at once or you should use the [asynchronous pull via the Receive method](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull).